# Android Studio compiles but java source is full of errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having some problems with Android Studio 0.1.5.

My app compiles and runs on my device.

But the java source code is full of red errors with 
Cannot resolve Symbol

This only seems to happen with components that are in libs (ex Roboguice)

Here is my build.gradle (though the problem looks more on Android Studio)

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files(
            'libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1.jar',
            'libs/gson-2.2.2.jar',
            'libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar',
            'libs/javax.inject-1.jar',
            'libs/roboguice-2.0b4.jar',
            'libs/roboguice-sherlock-1.0.jar',
    )

    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:android-ColorPickerPreference')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Do you have any hints?
Thanks.

Comment: try this in Android Studio 0.1.6 it was just released.

Comment: Thanks #Borys. I did it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I solved by selecting those libraries and then added as library.